# A question about linear approximation.

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

Since we know that in a good linear approximation, $L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a).$
But what if $f'(a)$ does not exist?
How to prove that if a function has a good linear approximation, then
it must be differentiable? Thanks a lot!

Definition of a good linear approximation:
$f$ has a good linear approximation near $a$ when there exists a line with equation $y=L(x)$ and function $E(x)$ s.t. $f(x)=L(x)+E(x), \forall x$ at and near $a$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{E(x)}{x-a}=0.$

Comment: You would need to very rigorously define what "good" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One definition of having a good linear approximation for $f$ at $a$ is 
$$
f(x)=f(a)+c(x-a)+\epsilon(x-a)
$$
where $\epsilon(x-a)$, the error term, is a function that satisfies the following
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\epsilon(x-a)}{x-a}=0
$$
Then, that $f$ is differentiable basically follows immediately, by subtracting $f(a)$, dividing by $x-a$ and taking the limit as $x\to a$ showing that the function is differentiable at $a$, with value $c$.

edit: I see now this is exactly how you define having a good linear approximation, so I will add more details to the above explanation, 
$$
f(x)=f(a)+c(x-a)+\epsilon(x-a)
\implies f(x)-f(a)=c(x-a)+\epsilon(x-a)\\
\implies\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=c+\frac{\epsilon(x-a)}{x-a}
$$
and thus taking the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=c+\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\epsilon(x-a)}{x-a}\\
\implies f'(a)=c
$$

Comment: Oh, when I try to prove it, I try to find the $L(x)$, like $L(x)=f(a)+k(x-a).$ It seems the same as your $f(a)+c(x-a).$ But what if $c$ does not exit? Or there is another meaning of $c$? Thanks!

Comment: @User329532 Isn't your hypothesis "$f$ has a good approximation"? Follow you definition, "$f$ has a good approximation" means $f(x)=f(a)+c(x-a)+E(x)(x-a)$ for some $c$ and $E$.

Comment: Here we don't know what the $c$ means, and what $c$ is. However, after some computing and thinking, we know that $c$ must be the derivative of $f$ at $a$, hence $c$ is unique.

Comment: @User329532 I second what Eric is saying, this was how i interpreted the problem

Comment: Thanks! I think I find what my logical problem is.